# Facebook API - FQL - How to read places where my friends were tagged

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How to read places where my friends were tagged ?
I found sth like this, but this example is not working for me .

or do I have to check piece by piece

```
SELECT page_id, author_uid FROM location_post WHERE xxfriendIDxx IN tagged_uids  ??

{
"my_friends":"SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 100)",
"their_locations":"SELECT page_id, author_uid FROM location_post WHERE tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) LIMIT 100",
"those_places": "SELECT page_id, name, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #their_locations)"
}
```

Thx for help!

Comment: I attempted to find this using facebook's graph search.  I need to do the same query for a project I'm working with.  Here is the url when searching via facebook graph search.  It may provide some help. https://www.facebook.com/search/<id>/places/me/friends/places-visited/intersect

Answer (score 2):

The below query will give you all the places that your friends have been tagged.

`SELECT page_id, name, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM location_post
WHERE author_uid IN
 (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))`

Make sure you have enabled the friends_photos, friends_checkins and friends_status permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately No. Your query will give me places in posts that were created by my friends. What about places in posts created by their friends ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as you do not have permission to look through your friend's friends posts.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any data either until I changed your `their_locations` sub-query to this:

```
SELECT page_id, author_uid FROM location_post WHERE 
  tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) 
    OR author_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) 
  LIMIT 100
```

It still isn't returning some location tagged posts that I can see using `/FRIEND_USERNAME/locations`.

There are other friends I know who post location tagged items all the time, but their privacy settings must be inhibiting these from being returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `user_tagged_places` permission. `API V-4`

```
<?php
//permissions array
     echo '<li><a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_tagged_places' ) ) . '"> Login    With Facebook</a></li>';
//call field
     echo '<pre>' . echo $graphObject['tagged_places']  . '</pre>'; 
?>
```